# Suppress the list of drivers when ogr2ogr fails

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, command-line, drivers

I'm quite sick of seeing this spammy output when ogr2ogr fails:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `foo.csv' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `JPEG2000'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `MBTiles'
  -> `EEDA'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
...
```

Is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: On windows you can pipe your stdout or stderr to nul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe

Comment: I don't want to lose all the output. I would still want the first two lines approximately.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows for example with `findstr`

```
ogrinfo foo.csv |findstr /V "^..->"
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `foo.bar' with the following drivers.
```

The command drops also lines from the normal output if lines contain string `->` starting from the third character of a line so the method is not totally solid.